# Import amended work item type fails with XML Validation Errors

Tags: tfs, xml-validation, tfs-workitem

I am attempting to add a list of suggested values to a field in TFS on a particular work item type.

I have successfully managed to use witexport to generate the .xml relating to the work item type

witexport /f "filename" /t "tfsuri" /p "tfsproject" /n "workitemtype" 
and am using the following syntax for import
witimport /f "fielname" /t "tfsuri" /p "tfsproject"

but when I attempt to reimport it fails due to several instances of the following Xml validation errors.

Xml Validation error at row n, column n: The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty

The xml at this line looks like

`<Control Type="WebpageControl" LabelPosition="Top" Dock="Fill">`

Xml Validaton error at row n, column n: The Element 'Control cannot contain child element 'LinksControlOptions' because the parent element's content model is empty

`<Tab Label="All Links">
<Control Type="LinksControl" LabelPosition="Top" Name="OtherLinks">
<LinksControlOptions>
<LinkColumns>`

The errors (line no's) are no where near the changes I have made so I deceided to try and simply export and import without making any changes and still receive the same errors as above.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem by exporting and importing the work item type via the IDE in Visual Studio.

Tools - Process Editor - Work Item Types - Import/Export WIT

The key step during the export phase was to select 'No' to the question 'Would you like to include the Global List Definition'.

I was then able to make my change and successfully reimport